# How to drive NPN transistor based on this circuit?

Tags: 555, npn, pnp

I just built a fan speed controller, using the following schematic:

[image: schematic]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/FGH/9VJO/FHTAIQK6/FGH9VJOFHTAIQK6.MEDIUM.jpg))</sub>

Now if you connect 12V from 555 and connect pin 7 to the blue CPU fan wire, it controls the speed, but whenever the PWM signal is approx 20% duty cycle, the fan runs approx 80% of full speed.

I liked the simplistic design and want to someday turn this into an LED dimmer. But I am not sure how to drive a N-channel FET or NPN transistor with the switched ground as opposed to the normal switched Vcc.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin 7 of the 555 is an open-collector output, while pin 3 is a normal totem-pole output that can be used to drive a transistor (BJT or MOSFET).

Comment: don't forget a resistor between pin 3 and the NPN base, the MOSFET OTOH can be driven directly

Comment: So how could I modify the schematic to use pin 3 instead of 7 with the same amount of parts? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Just connect your transistor to pin 3. If it's a BJT, use a current-limiting resistor between pin 3 and the base. Connect the emitter/source to ground. Connect your load between the positive supply and the collector/drain. No other modification is needed, but note that the duty-cycle control will now work "backwards" -- when the pin 7 output is on, your transistor will be off, and vice-versa.

Comment: Works great! Thanks! Care to explain why this works? I've never seen a potentiometer directly on pin 3, thought it would interfere. Apparently not tho.

Comment: You can think of pin 3 as being connected alternately to Vcc and Gnd. When it is high, the bottom half of R1 and D1 conduct current to charge C1. When C1 reaches 2/3 Vcc, pin 3 goes low, and the top half of R1 and D2 conduct current to discharge C1. When C1 reaches 1/3 Vcc, the output goes high and the cycle starts over. Since the two halves of R1 -- with the split being determined by the wiper position -- are used independently, you get a wide range of control over the output duty cycle.